# log in with facebook php sdk

Tags: php, facebook, authentication, sdk

I'm trying to implement log in with facebook (php sdk)

The main code is like below:

```
require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';

Facebook\FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication('app id goes here...', 'app secret goes here...');
$facebook = new Facebook\FacebookRedirectLoginHelper('http://example.com/some-segment/facebook-auth/index.php/');

try {
    if ($session = $facebook->getSessionFromRedirect()) {
        $_SESSION['facebook'] = $session->getToken();
    }

    if (isset($_SESSION['facebook'])) {
        $session = new Facebook\FacebookSession($_SESSION['facebook']);
        $request = new Facebook\FacebookRequest($session, 'GET', '/me');
        $request = $request->execute();


        $user = $request->getGraphObject()->asArray();

        $_SESSION['fb-user'] = $user;


    }
} catch (Facebook\FacebookRequestException $e) {
    // when facebook returns an error
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    // A local issue
}
```

On the page, where user could log in with facebook i have code like this:

```
<?php 

    if (!isset($_SESSION['facebook'])): ?>
    <?php 

    $scope = array('public_profile', 'email', 'user_birthday', 'user_location');

    ?>
        <a href="<?php echo $facebook->getLoginUrl($scope);?>"log in with facebookk!</a>
    <?php else: ?>
        <p>Logged as: <?php echo $_SESSION['user']['name']; ?><br/><a href="signout.php">log out</a></p>
    <?php endif; ?>
```

On the facebook developers site, app is configured correctly. Valid OAuth redirect URIs is like above.

And now, once im clicking log in with facebook anchor tag, when i'm var_dump $_SESSION i have something like this.

array(1) { ["FBRLH_state"]=> string(32) "c9e540b9afcd75c5b8c39ff5b1fcc36e" }

Don't know what it is and how to fix that, dont even know how to debug that. Any suggestions?

Comment: looks like successful retrieval of session

Comment: @RobertPounder its somekind of error, success data on return should look like array() with id,birthday,email... etc

Comment: success data should be the session id should it not? failure should be 0

Comment: have you var dumped $request?